# Haskell type-level projection

Tags: haskell, type-level-computation

Is there any way of defining a type level projection without using type families?

I do it like so:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
type family Project t :: *
type instance Project [r] = r ,
```

but I really only ever use one instance of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `MultiParamTypeClass` and `FunctionalDependencies`, though without knowing why you're using it it's hard to say if this is sufficient.

```
class Project k a | k -> a
instance Project [r] r

> :t undefined :: Project String r => r
undefined :: Project String r => r :: Char
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure where you are going to use that exactly. But I tend to use type level projections only to satisfy the haskell type system. What I usually do is to define a function like this:

```
project :: [a] -> a
project = undefined
```

Now using project on an object of type `[a]` will give me an object of type `a`.

Another function which I use (although sometimes) along with the above is [`asTypeOf`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v%3aasTypeOf).

Comment: I am going to use it for fun and profit. Your answer is a nifty trick, but I don't use those. Thanks nevertheless.